# A word for "of any kind"

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be a good word for *of any kind* in the following context?

Context: *The client may come up with requirements that can be of any kind*.

(Meaning that the requirements are potentially unlimitedly specific and diverse)

The best I could come up with is *indefinitely custom*.

Answer (score 1):

[***assorted***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assorted)

> : consisting of various kinds : assorted chocolates

[***miscellaneous***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miscellaneous)

> : consisting of diverse things or members :  heterogeneous

[***varied***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/varied)

> : having many forms or types : including many different things

[***diverse***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diverse)

> :  differing from one another :  unlike : people with diverse
>   interests

[***eclectic***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eclectic)

> : including things taken from many different sources

[***motley***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motley)

> :  composed of diverse often incongruous elements :a motley crowd

[***sundry***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sundry)

> : made up of different things

[***disparate***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disparate)

> : different from each other

All from M-W.